# Create File at Android Api 26

Tags: android, file

I want to create gallery app for trying.I am using Android studio 3 and android api 26 and 27.
I want to take a picture from my app.I've added a button to my layout and then created related method. at this method I had checked that the user accepted appropriate permission or not like this:

```
public void takePhoto(View view) {
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
   callCameraApp();
}
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_RESULT);
    }
}
```

before camera started I first create file:

```
private void callCameraApp() {
    //        Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    Intent callCamAppIntent = new Intent();
    callCamAppIntent.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    File photoFile = null;
    try {
        photoFile = createImageFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }....
```

at this method i had generated image name and then I create file:

```
    public File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmdd_hhmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "IMAGE_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", mGalleryFolder);
    return image;
}
```

but I do not know why when my App is started for firs time `photoFile` is null?and I got error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                         Process: com.groot.intentandcamera, PID: 30499
                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }} to activity {com.groot.intentandcamera/com.groot.intentandcamera.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.io.File.getCanonicalPath()' on a null object reference
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4268)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4312)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1644)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.io.File.getCanonicalPath()' on a null object reference
                                                                           at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:696)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:401)
                                                                           at com.groot.intentandcamera.MainActivity.callCameraApp(MainActivity.java:80)
                                                                           at com.groot.intentandcamera.MainActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(MainActivity.java:127)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:7420)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7271)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4264)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4312) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1644) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

but for second time, everything is ok.I got the right permission from the user.also I have added these permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

at the manifest file. what's the points I have forgot?

*****Edit****************

This is my Uri:

```
String authorities = getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".fileProvider";
Uri imgUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, authorities, photoFile);
allCamAppIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,imgUri);
startActivityForResult(callCamAppIntent, ACTIVITY_START_CAMERA_APP);
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.io.File.getCanonicalPath()' on a null object reference
                                                                           at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:696)
                                                                        `.

Comment: You did not post code with getUriForFile().

Comment: @greenapps :`String authorities = getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".fileProvider";
        Uri imgUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, authorities, photoFile);
        callCamAppIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,imgUri);`

Comment: Post code in your post. Not in comments.

Comment: @greenapps  I updated my post.

Comment: Probably photoFile==null. Check before use.

Comment: @greenapps dude the problem is here but it is not to be null because I call this method `createImageFile()` and this method create a file.look this method at top. I think createTempFile() has a problem.

Comment: No it did not create a file to begin with. And throwing an IOException you should put a toast in that catch block and not continu if there is an exception but return. By the way: it is wrong to create a file yourself. You only need a file name/path which you give to the camera app. The camera app will create a file if the user takes a picture.

Comment: So check also if it is null before use.

Comment: @greenapps you mean is, I use `Intent data` that comes from camera?

Comment: ????? Did i use the word intent? Did i use the word data?

Comment: how can I use the file that is provided from camera?

Comment: Wel that is a whole other story. As long as you have that nullpointerexception the camera app will not come in play. Your post was already a mess using four code blocks so nobody knows what you are doing and now you want to know something different.

Comment: @greenapps thank 's dude.